# How to click increase counter in listview Android

Tags: java, android

I want to increase counter android in `ListView` adapter, but next click row always failure increased.

```
counting_update_cycle = actual.getJson().getCycle();
counting_update = counting_update_cycle;
holder.counting.setText(String.valueOf(counting_update_cycle));

//action tambah
holder.btntambahekekusi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.counting.setText(String.valueOf(counting_update));
        counting_update++;

    }
});
```

Comment: Can we see more of the code?

Comment: What are `holder` and `actual`?

Comment: array object = actual

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
counting_update_cycle = actual.getJson().getCycle();
counting_update = counting_update_cycle;
holder.counting.setText(String.valueOf(counting_update_cycle));

//action tambah
holder.btntambahekekusi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // added code
        counting_update_cycle = actual.getJson().getCycle();
        counting_update = counting_update_cycle;

        holder.counting.setText(String.valueOf(counting_update));

        // update instance property of object
        actual.getJson().setCycle(counting_update++);
    }
});
```

Comment: `actual.getJson().setCycle` probably should look like `actual.setCycle`. Also, `counting_update` is an unnecessary duplicate of the previous line variable

Comment: This is only for idea.
You can make better algorithm to avoid duplicate code.

P.S: I think 'holder' is cell view, 'actual' is object for cell view content.